# How do I use the condition element in ant to set another property?

Tags: java, ant

I have a build.xml to use with ant, and I'm trying to put a condition within a target:

First I set the property here which works OK:

```
<condition property="isWindows">
    <os family="windows"/>
</condition>
```

Then I try to use it in the target:

```
<target name="-post-jar">
    <condition property="isWindows" value="true">
         <!-- set this property, only if isWindows set -->
         <property name="launch4j.dir" location="launch4j" />
    </condition>

    <!-- Continue doing things, regardless of property -->
    <move file="${dist.jar.dir}" tofile="myFile"/>
    <!-- etc -->
</target>
```

I'm getting an error: "condition doesn't support the nested "property" element."
The questions are : How do I correctly put a condition inside a target and why is the error referring to a 'nested' property?

Comment: That looks exactly like the syntax in the ant docs. Are you sure you're not creating a <property> element inside the condition tasks (where you've written "do things in here")?.

Comment: Ah...I am creating another property in there (the next line was <property name="launch4j.dir" location="launch4j" /> Is that a no-no?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`condition` is used to define a property, but not to execute some actions based on the value of a property.

Use a [target with `if` or `unless` attribute](http://ant.apache.org/manual/properties.html#if+unless) to execute some tasks based on the value of the property.

Comment: I did originally have the target + an if, but the target name is fixed (-post-jar) so I'm unable to duplicate it, hence trying to put some conditions within the target itself. Thanks JB.

Comment: Just make your -post-jar target depend on another target having an if attribute.

Comment: Thanks JB Nizet. Solved by re-arranging the tasks, adding an <antcall> to a new target, then putting an if="isWindows" on this new target. The nesting error I believe referred to putting a <property> tag right after the <condition property="isWindows" in my original code.

Answer (score 1):

The criteria for the [condition](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/condition.html) is nested inside of the `condition` element.

You specify the property that you want set using the `property` attribute, and the value when the condition is met using the `value` attribute on the `condition` element.  Additionally, you can set a value for the property the condition is not met with the `else` attribute.

To check whether or not a property is set as criteria for a `condition`, use [`isset`](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/conditions.html)

```
<condition property="isWindows">
    <os family="windows"/>
</condition>   

<target name="-post-jar">
    <!--Only set property if isWindows -->
    <condition property="launch4j.dir" value="launch4j">
         <isset property="isWindows"/>
    </condition>

    <!-- Continue doing things, regardless of property -->
    <move file="${dist.jar.dir}" tofile="myFile"/>
    <!-- etc -->
</target>
```